# Square Root and ++ Operators for BigInteger and BigDecimal

Tags: java, operator-overloading, operators, biginteger, bigdecimal

Is there any ready-made Java library for operations over BigInteger and BigDecimal objects?

I'd like to use square root and ++ operators.

Thank you

P.S. BigInteger.add() should be used instead of ++, I got it.
What about square root from BigInteger?

Comment: Well have you examined the documentation for the classes?

Comment: yes and unfortunately I found no word about getting square from BigInteger

Comment: @sunny if you look at my answer, you will find that there is no need for a dedicated `square()` method. Plain multiplication does the job.

Comment: Sorry I meant square root. Fixed it in a question

Answer (score 2):

[BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is **immutable**. That makes something like the `++`-operator on it conceptually impossible. You can not change the value of a given `BigInteger`, just like you can't do it with `String`.

## Incrementing

You always have to create a new `BigInteger` that holds the incremented value (you can then of course store the reference to that `BigInteger` in the same variable).

Edit: As pointed out in the comment, "incrementing" would look like:

```
BigInteger result = a.add(BigInteger.ONE);
```

or

```
a = a.add(BigInteger.ONE);
```

Note that both lines do not *change* the value of the `BigInteger` which `a` originally points to. The last line creates a **new** BigInteger and stores the reference to it in `a`.

## Calculating the Square

You can calculate the square of a `BigInteger` like this:

```
BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
BigInteger a_square = a.multiply(a); // a^2 == a * a
```

or

```
BigInteger a_square = a.pow(2);
```

## Square Root

The code is taken from https://gist.github.com/JochemKuijpers/cd1ad9ec23d6d90959c549de5892d6cb .
It uses simple bisection and a clever upper bound. Note that `a.shiftRight(x)` is equivalent to `a / 2^x` (only for non-negative numbers, but that is all we deal with, anyway)

```
BigInteger sqrt(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger b = n.shiftRight(5).add(BigInteger.valueOf(8));
    while (b.compareTo(a) >= 0) {
        BigInteger mid = a.add(b).shiftRight(1);
        if (mid.multiply(mid).compareTo(n) > 0) {
            b = mid.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        } else {
            a = mid.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
    }
    return a.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

## Using Operators Instead of Methods

Operator overloading like in *C++* is not possible in Java.

Comment: to increment `BigInteger` use `BigInteger result =  a.add(BigInteger.ONE);`

Comment: thnk you , got it

Comment: to be complete, add also this square variant `BigInteger result = a.pow(2);`